# php sqlite use database connection in several scripts

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I have a webpage where I have a section monitoring. The whole page is connected with a SQLite database. Now I tried to connect at the very first page to the database as an object `$database = new project_db();` and store this in a `$_SESSION['db]=$database;`. For this page it worked fine. But for the monitoring page and all other pages are called it worked not. I got the error

> SQLite3::lastErrorMsg, warning: object has not been correctly initialised

Therefore I tried to open and close the database on each page separate. That worked for the pages which are called by the user. index.php to menu.php and so on. But monitoring is called every minute as a separate file. There I get always the problem with the SQLite3 error message. Even if I try to create a new object here by opening a new conncetion. Then I get the exception error that it is not possible to open the database.
How can I connect several times to the same SQLITE3 database in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, how I can open persistent connection to my sqlite database. I use PDO.

```
$database = new PDO("sqlite:database.db","","",array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
    ));
```

Then it is possible to use a connection several times, without closing after a script ends.